# How do I install rosjava hydro on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu-trusty, ubuntu, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to linux and to ROS, however when I try and run sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-catkin ros-hydro-ros python-wstool
all I get is:

Reading package lists... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-hydro-catkin
E: Unable to locate package ros-hyrdo-ros

How do I resolve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191209/how-do-i-install-rosjava-hydro-on-ubuntu-14.04?/) by [pickandroll3](https://answers.ros.org/users/20085/pickandroll3/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-08-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check the target distibutions for ROS Hydro (http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#hydro-medusa-aug-2013), 14.04 is not supported.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1